# Ethernet constantly disconnecting - troubleshooter error code 0x80004005

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, troubleshooting, windows-error-reporting

I've reinstalled windows 10 twice and the error still remains, I would like to get this fixed, any help would be appreciated. Process to get this error messages is to navigate to Network Connections and Diagnose this connection (Ethernet and Wifi ).

Wifi manages to stay stable but is low performance.

Clicked WiFi bars in System Tray, then "Troubleshoot" then got the message: An unexpected error has occurred. The troubleshooting wizard can't continue.

Error windows say's - An error occurred while loading the troublershooter: An unexpected error has occurred.
The troubleshooting wizard can't continue

Package ID: Unknown

Path: Unknown

Error code: 0x80004005

Source: Command line

User: MY PC NAME

Context: Restricted

Error message:
[image]

Here are some steps I have tired:

1. Tried disabling and re-enabling WiFi adapter (still doesn't work)
2. In network adapters pressed "Diagnose", got: An error occurred while loading the troubleshooter
3. Ran `sfc /scannow` from elevated Command Prompt - completed with no repairs needed
4. I've tried resetting my TCP/IP in command prompt useing `netsh int ip reset` and got a single failed reset.[netsh int ip reset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JrYi.png)

I keep trying the same things as listed above, hoping something will just magically work, but it's proven unsuccessful. I've done everything I could possibly think of.

Comment: Have you considered replacing the ethernet cable?

Comment: Or tried a USB Ethernet Card?   It is NOT a Windows 10 issue.

Comment: Switched over to USB wifi adapter and get the same issue and error message.
I've swapped Ethernet cables with not difference.

Comment: Ethernet in WIndows 10, the system portion of it, is rock solid... What ethernet adapter/chipset are you using and what switch? I remember years back a certain model of Intellinet switch would not link properly with a Realtek 8111E Ethernet chipset (I think, might be wrong on the specific model), but situations like this are rare today. I would also be interested in what the switch shows when this occurs, if a link is show (physical link) on either/both ends of the connection, etc. Troubleshooting Ethernet is generally a pretty simple thing... basic information gathering and elimination.